# How to make PS script run against each line of a csv?

Tags: powershell

I currently have a PS script that is used for remediation of breached user accounts in a hybrid O365/On-prem AD environment. The script currently works as intended, enabling MFA, logging, resetting passwords, removing mailbox rules, etc.

There are times when we must remediate more than just a few accounts. That being said I am trying to set up the script to go line by line in a CSV file with headers to pull the users UPN name and execute the script for each UPN name in a csv.

Currently the script cant take and run multiple inputs for each function at once time so the script would need to re-run again. Additionally, the script pulls cmdlets and etc for each time it runs, being able to speed up the script by say keeping the initial session open would be a bonus.

Ideally, the result would be the script continue to run without requiring me to enter another UPN.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. 
Although your question belongs to http://stackoverflow.com/ rather,  
it could be answered here if you [edit] your question and provide a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Maybe something like `foreach ($UserAccnt in (Import-Csv -Path .\yourfilename.csv) ) {# call the script here using $UserAccnt.UPN as a parameter }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using `import-csv` you can loop through each item with a `foreach`.

```
$myCSV = import-csv $theCSVfile

foreach($row in $myCSV){
    myPSscript($row.UPNname)
}
```

Or to update the $row.UPNname field with new data from your PS script:

```
$myCSV = import-csv $theCSVfile

foreach($row in $myCSV){
    $newUPNname = myPSscript($row.UPNname)
    $row.UPNname = $newUPNname
}
export-csv $myCSV
```

If you are working with more than just the UPNname, you will need to pass those fields or the entire record ($row) of data.

```
$myCSV = import-csv $theCSVfile
$mynewCSV = @()
foreach($row in $myCSV){
    $newRow = myPSscript($row)
    $mynewCSV += $newRow
}
export-csv $mynewCSV
```

Comment: Would I need to modify the script itself to continue  back tot he first function to continue running? so it does not simply end?

Comment: No.  The foreach will call an instance of your script for each row in the data.

Comment: Gotcha, I will give it a shot.

Comment: that works, just as your said.  if I echo $upn it will output the contents of the csv file.  But the rest of my script wont do anything with them.

Comment: If you are manipulating the data and want to write it back to the CSV you will need to pass it back and forth or build this code into your main script and write the data out with ```export-csv```  I will update the answer with a few more starting points.

Comment: not really writing back.  The script should just take that field and enter it as a variable to run the script against that username that is contained within that field.

if it makes it easier to understand here is a scrubbed version of the script

https://pastebin.com/hggUm4Bu

Comment: @AndrewDiaz It looks like you need to put _your entire script_ inside that foreach block.  Otherwise it looks like it will only operate on the last record.

Comment: Haza!!  That worked *doh*.  I guess one last thing that would be a nicety. im sure i could figure it out.  How about doing something like if there is no csv file then allow me to enter the upn manually.

Comment: Something like: ```if (Test-Path 'C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Book1.csv'){$csv = import-csv 'C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Book1.csv'} else{$csv=@();$singleUPN = Read-Host 'Enter a UPN:';$csv+=@{UPN = $singleUPN}```  Could you please mark the main as correct answer?